# Filter on collection and merge results in another collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB 4.2.9 and have the following requirements:

- Collection 'A' has multiple documents with a string field 'status' that I need to filter on
- Collection 'B' has multiple documents

**Collection A**

```json
{ _id: "1",
  status: "Report",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "Excellent",
  ReportNo: "A1"
},
{ _id: "2",
  status: "Open",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "",
  ReportNo: ""
},
{ _id: "3",
  status: "Draft",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "",
  ReportNo: ""
},
{ _id: "4",
  status: "Report",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "Great",
  ReportNo: "A4"
}
```

**Collection B**

```json
{ _id: "98",
  status: "Archived",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "So So",
  ReportNo: "X2"
},
{ _id: "99",
  status: "Archived",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "Great",
  ReportNo: "X1"
}
```

**Resulting View**

```json
{ _id: "1",
  status: "Report",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "Excellent",
  ReportNo: "A1"
},
{ _id: "4",
  status: "Report",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "Great",
  ReportNo: "A4"
},
{ _id: "98",
  status: "Archived",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "So So",
  ReportNo: "X2"
},
{ _id: "99",
  status: "Archived",
  type: "Academy",
  rating: "Great",
  ReportNo: "X1"
}
```

My goal is to create an aggregation view so that I can filter on a status value in Collection 'A' and then merge those results with Collection 'B' and show in the view ?

I can filter on Collection 'A' using the match call, just can't see how to merge resulting documents into Collection 'B'

Comment: Have you checked out [views](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/#:~:text=A%20MongoDB%20view%20is%20a,permission%20to%20query%20the%20view.)? You may want to update your question with some sample documents from collection A and B and the expected output so we can reproduce the issue and see what we can help

Comment: @ray Yes, I've used views before just can't seem to see how to do a $lookup without trying to match something. I have added some simple example documents if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understandings, your "merge" behaviour is actually a union view of filtered view of collection A and collection B.

With MongoDB v4.2, you can use `$facet` to handle collection A and collection B separately.

- simply perform filtering on A
- perform uncorrelated `$lookup` on B

wrangle the result and merge them together to get the union view that you are looking for.

```js
db.createCollection(
  "unionView",
  {
    "viewOn" : "A",
    "pipeline" : [
  {
    "$facet": {
      "A": [
        {
          "$match": {
            status: "Report"
          }
        }
      ],
      "B": [
        {
          $limit: 1
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "B",
            "pipeline": [],
            "as": "B"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$B"
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$B"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      all: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$A",
          "$B"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$all"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$all"
    }
  }
]
  }
)
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nYiGS7EThtg) for your reference.

---

With MongoDB v4.4+, you can create a view with `$unionWith`

```js
db.createCollection(
  "unionView",
  {
    "viewOn" : "A",
    "pipeline" : [
  {
    "$match": {
      status: "Report"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "B"
    }
  }
]
  }
)
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/whh067oa_Cb) for your reference.

Comment: That looks promising however it looks like `$unionWith` was released in 4.4 and we are running 4.2.9

Comment: @richnwilson sorry my bad. update the answer to use a version using `$facet`, which should be available in v4.2

Comment: I think for now, I'm going to build the 'join' in the endpoint and wait until we migrate to 4.4 to use the `$unionWith`.

Comment: @richnwilson sensible choice. I actually suspect the `$setUnion` may not perform well with large dataset generated by `$facet`. You may need to take care of some 16MB document limit also if the `$facet` is generating a lot of results.